# Bug in styling cakephp form select box

Tags: php, css, cakephp, css-selectors

I have this code. My problem is none of the style is getting applied on the select menu. But its getting applied on the input box. Am i doing anything wrong here?

### HTML

```
<div class="signup">
<div class="personal">
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('/users/signup'));
echo $this->Form->input('name');
$options = array('m'=>'Male','f'=>'Female');
echo $this->Form->input('gender', array( 'options'=>$options,'type'=>'select', 'label'=>'Gender'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Sign up');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.signup{
 /* class style */
}

.signup .personal form input[type=text],[type=select]{
border: 1px solid #cacaca;
border-radius: 2px;
font: 12px arial;
height: 20px;
width: 150px;
}
```

### HTML OUTPUT

```
<div class="signup">
    <div class="personal">
        <form action="/appraisal/users/signup" /users/signup="/users/signup" id="UserSignupForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div style="display:none;">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input text">
                <label for="UserName">Name</label>
                <input name="data[User][name]" type="text" id="UserName"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input select">
                <label for="UserGender">Gender</label>
                <select name="data[User][gender]" id="UserGender">
                    <option value="m">Male</option>
                    <option value="f">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="submit">
                <input  type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct selector is `select`, not `[type=select]`.

That style of selector reserved for an `input` element (e.g. `input[type=email], input[type=text]`)

Comment: Also `.signup .personal form input[type=text],[type=select]` is overkill and can slow pages down in extreme cases. `.signup [input[type=text]` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) might help you to get a css for Dropdown list. As Ross said, `select` is used as a selector to give some UI enhancements to select box.

[This tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/styling-forms-with-attribute-selectors/) must help you to understand the css selectors available for Form Elements.